# PHP file_get_contents() and PHPSESSID

Tags: php, session, cookies, file-get-contents

I can't use file_get_contents with session cookies! There are 9 cookies.. My code:

```
<?
$ip=explode('<a href="trade?t=',file_get_contents('http://csgolounge.com/'));
$ip=explode('">',$ip[1]);
$ip=$ip[0];
echo $ip;

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Cookie: __utma=123\r\n__utmb=123\r\n__utmc=123\r\n__utmt=123\r\n__utmz=123\r\nid=123\r\nPHPSESSID=123\r\ntkz=123\r\ntoken=123\r\n'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

session_write_close();
$ip2=explode('<a class="buttonright" href="',file_get_contents('http://csgolounge.com/trade?t=' . $ip, false, $context)); // This doesn't return the url...
$ip2=explode('">Add on Steam</a>',$ip2[1]);
$ip2=$ip2[0];
echo $ip2;
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please help!

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Trying to grab url from csgolounge.com
(steam://friends/add/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

Comment: try using html parser like http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Comment: I can't parse without session cookies...

Comment: for sure you can because file_gets_contents returns the html string which can be parsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies in `Cookie` header are separated using semicolons (not newlines).

Your `Cookie` header should look like this:

```
'header' => 'Cookie: __utma=123; __utmb=123; __utmc=123; __utmt=123; __utmz=123; id=123; PHPSESSID=123; tkz=123; token=123'
```